# Nginx redirect and third level domains

Tags: nginx

SOLVED (was another configuration, nginx was ok)

I've nginx as a reverse proxy.
I've domain www.example.com, with https, and I've these confs in my example.conf:

```
## Redirect from non-www to www, https or not
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.cm/privkey.pem;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

## Redirect from www to https www
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {   
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name www.example.com;
    [...]    
}
```

I've to add a third level domain: https://test.example.com in
I've add a new test.domain.conf with this confs

```
## reditect from http to hhtps
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.example.com;
    return 301 https://test.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {   
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name test.example.com;
    [...]    
}
```

The problem is that if I go to https://test.example.com/login I'm redirect to https://www.example.com/login, so my request is "intercepted" by the non-www to www redirect rule in domain.conf

What's wrong?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading. The `server` blocks with the new `server_name` do not appear to be included.

Comment: Thanks! If I run "nginx-T" I see also confs from test.example.com

Comment: I solved, was an error on my docker-compose configuration, thanks however :)